# Efficient tree-based dialogue system?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a simple tree based dialogue system. its a basic game of click to advance the story, with different choice to choose, leading player to a different story path.

What I did was, I create a plethora of gameObject called Convo. Each Convo contain Text(Component) , and Children to determine which character is on screen, and a tag in those child to display their inflection(ex. sad happy etc.).
Ex

- A-0-1 (Text: " John: Hey, what's going on?") (with tag "Choice" if it's the last convo)

  - John(with tag "Idle")
  - Jane(with tag "Irritated")

[Story path picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHTH0.png)

There's 2 variable: CurrentDialogue(string) and DialogueTracking(int).

On each click, I check if current convo has tag "Choice". If there isn't, I use CurrentDialogue(string) to find gameobject with exact name and display it's text. then increase DialogueTracking by one,

then I modified CurrentDialogue(string) from  A-0-1 to A-0-2 and so on using DialogueTracking, and When there's tag "choice" (Ex.A-0-4) , DialogueTracking(int) get reset to one, so it's A-1-1 instead of A-1-5 after player choose a choice.

Here's the problem, after a lot of convo and many story path, I realize my newbie mistake. The code turn into big o' if/else,(the comparing of which choice go which path)

I'm quite new to programming and unity, If anyone could guide me in the right direction on ways to help me learn how to create this system to be clean and efficient , that would be really great!

Thank you!

Comment: maybe structure it using interfaces? https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest making `DialogueManager` `Component` that will hold all of your dialogues and each of these should hold reference to other dialogues. Then after displaying dialogue you can check if it has multiple children or just one ( or none ) and display some dialog/popup to choose from keys of these.

In code example it would be like :

```c#
[Serializable]
public class Dialogue
{
    [SerializeField]
    Dictionary<string, Dialogue> _dialogues;

    [SerializeField]
    string _dialogueText;

    public Dialogue(string text)
    {
        _dialogues = new Dictionary<string, Dialogue>();
        _dialogueText = text;
    }

    public string GetText() { return _dialogueText; }      

    public bool HasManyPaths() { return _dialogues.Count > 1; }

    public string[] GetKeys() { return _dialogues.Keys; }

    public Dialogue GetDialogue(string key) { return _dialogues[key]; }
}
```

Now you should fill this within your `Unity` inspector and make `DialogueManager` `Component` to manage your `Dialogue`s :

```c#
public class DialogueManager
    : Component
{
    [SerializeField]
    Dialogue _currentDialogue;

    public void InitializeDialogue() 
    {
        string text = _currentDialogue.GetText();
        // display the text
        if ( _currentDialogue.HasManyPaths() )
        {
            string[] keys = _currentDialogue.GetKeys();
            // display keys;
            string selected_key = // user input here
            _currentDialogue = _currentDialogue.GetDialogue(selected_key);
        }
        else
        {
            string key = _currentDialogue.GetKeys()[0];
            _currentDialogue = _currentDialogue.GetDialogue(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this method you can simply make your dialogues inside Unity editor and add `MonoBehaviour` script with something like this :

```c#
public void Start()
{
    GetComponent<DialogueManager>().InitializeDialogue();
}
```

Simple example of making dialogue tree would be :

```
{ currentDialogue [ "hello! choose 1 or 2" ]
    1.{ dialogue [ "you've chosen 1" ]
        . { dialogue [ "this ends dialogue" ] }
    }
    2. { dialogue [ "you've chosen 2" ]
        . { dialogue [ "now choose another number between 3 and 4" ]
            3. { dialogue [ "you've chosen 3" ] }
            4. { dialogue [ "you've chosen 4" ] }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! to be honest I only understand few line of the code as this is the first time I'm learning about Serialization.  From what I understand, my previous Text(component) will be replaced with single Dialogue(script) to store whole dialogue tree instead? and a single DialogueManager(script) is the one responsible for getting _currentDialogue from Dialogue(script) and displaying text and also get input to move to different path if there's choice right? I feel like I got it all wrong, can you clarify me more? Thanks!

Comment: @Irfx Basically you've understood it correctly. The Thing is I think you'll have to create some custom inspector for that but I'm not quite sure about that it's needed. :) If you need some more detils please comment and I'll try to make some screenshots and edit this answer to be more clear.